# Turbo repo with pnpm is looking up the incorrect react version when apps use different react versions

Tags: reactjs, typescript, pnpm, turborepo, pnpm-workspace

I have a turbo repo setup with pnpm, and we are adding a new client portal to our product suite. We have an old, internal web interface built on create react app, with a dependency on react 17. The new client portal is going to be built with NextJS, which has a dependency on react 18.

After adding the new app to the monorepo, I am getting errors from the typescript compiler in the React 17 project, because it is trying to look up the types for React 18.

I have tried playing with the hoist setting in `.npmrc` but have not had any luck. I have also deleted all the `node_modules` and cleared out the lock file a few times to try that.

How can I make the React 17 application look up the correct types?

Comment: Do you only have a single package.json? Because the standard solution is to make sure projects with different version requirements have their own package.json file.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans No. There is the root package.json that defines the commands for the whole mono repo, but then each package/app has it's own package.json

Comment: And you already deleted all the node_modules directories and reran the installer to make sure each dir has the correct node_modules content?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Yup. I can visually see that the react 17 app has react 17 linked into it's node_modules directory. Both for types and react itself. I've also purged the pnpm store to make sure it was 100% fresh.

Comment: And you've made sure to tell your TS config in your old app to use the react 17 types?

Comment: That was it. I had to add `react: node_modules/@types/react` to the paths.

Comment: @AdamLeBlanc I'm running into the same issue. Could you elaborate on how you fixed this? What paths did you add `react: node_modules/@types/react` to? Thx!